# Did Walker know the aliens existed, or was the twist of "Not Alone" a coincidence?

Tags: not-alone

I've just finished reading *Not Alone* (book 1) by Craig A. Falconer and I am confused about the twist.

Did Walker etc know aliens existed after all and they were trying some double bluff by saying the evidence was made up to put people off the trail, or was the evidence made up all along and coincidentally aliens just happened to exist and show themselves?